# client-server protocol in C++

Tags: c++, networking, protocol

I'm looking for a client-server protocol to use in my C++ local network application. This protocol should:

- support client-server schema
- support data packet sizes of 1-4 MB
- support at least 100 Hz request-response cycles
- use UDP (TCP would be good)
- be implemented in linux

The basic use case is writing a telemetry system to gather realtime data from local area devices using ethernet/IP networks. An MQTT or any publish-subscribe protocol is not useful for my use case.

Please feel free to ask for any details you see as relevant.

Comment: Just to clarify: you're looking for a protocol you want to implement yourself – or for a C++ library implementing such a protocol?

Comment: That would render your question off-topic then. So are you sure? ;)

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending **software** meeting specific requirements – not approaches, [languages](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/185), [technologies](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/185) or [algorithms](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/865/185).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I ended up using [Websockets](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455)

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket): "WebSocket is a computer communications protocol, providing full-duplex communication channels over a single TCP connection." Thus, Websockets runs on top of TCP exceeding at least one of my requirements.

I also found nice implementations like [this](https://docs.websocketpp.org/) for C++ and [this](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for Python. I 'm using them to exchange high volume of data with few overhead. It is great.